# Expected value of a number of events

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If I have a set of random events say
${\{A_{1}, A_{2}, ... A_{n}\}}$ and a number ${N=\sum_{1}^{n} I(A_{i})}$ where ${I(A_{i})}$ is the indicator function (basically ${N}$ is the number of events that happen after a random experiment).

Can anybody please tell me how can I find the **expected value** of ${N}$?

We assume that we know the probability of each event.

It would also be nice to know how is ${N}$ or its expected value called (if they have a particular name) and the actual value of the expected value (if it has a general formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1$ to $n$, define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if $A_i$ occurs, and $X_i=0$ if it doesn't.

Then $N=\sum_{i=1}^n  X_i$. By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E(N)=\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i).$$
If $p_i$ is the probability $A_i$ occurs, then $E(X_i)=p_i$.

Comment: Do you mean that E(N)=sum(E(X_i))? Because what you wrote there is actually N as you defined it earlier.

Comment: Thanks, it is supposed to be $E(X_i)$, fixed. Note that we are **not** assuming the $A_i$ are independent, linearity of expectation always holds.